# New Shapefile (Polygon) Disappearing in Edit Session ArcGIS 10.6.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, editing, arcgis-10.6

I created a shapefile in ArcCatalog and assigned it its coordinate system as I always do. I selected "polygon" as the type.

I added a generic topographic basemap to ArcMap.

Upon editing the new shapefile, if I hit save edits, the entire thing disappears and is not in the attribute table either. This has happened 4x now with new shapefiles, using a different basemap, and having nothing on but a basemap and new file.

Has anyone experienced this before or can pinpoint what I am doing wrong? I made a new polygon shapefile last month and did not have this problem! I have rebooted my computer as well to see if that was a glitch.

Comment: My guess it's the spatial index: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/modifying-indexes-in-shapefiles-by-adding-a-spatial-index.htm  -- any reason you're using shapefiles instead of fgdb?

Comment: Which coordinate system did you assign? And what place on 'earth' are you making an edit?

Comment: Do you have a definition query set on the layer?